# how i will call a function inside the Application didiFinishLaunchingWithOption

Tags: iphone

I want to use show function inside "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

```
-(void)show
{
NSLog(@"AAA");
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    




[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `[self show];` before `Return`

Answer (score 1):

use [self show]; inside your application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.